# ARCore bind texture not compatible with GL_TEXTURE_2D

Tags: android, opengl-es, arcore

I'm trying to use ARCore with my custom 3D render engine.

I was expecting to configure my background (camera's pictures stream) to render as usual (since I already use it with other AR lib ) : create an OpenGL texture, a plane, set texture as material and ask ARCore to bind texture on update, but it seems that only `GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES` can be used (I used `GL_TEXTURE_2D`)

It this the only way to bind the texture for an OpenGl renderer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the only way.
The texture must be GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES.
Also note that you need to modify your fragment shader too:

```
 #extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require
    precision mediump float;
    uniform samplerExternalOES texture;
    varying vec2 v_textureCoords;
    void main() {
      gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture, v_textureCoords);
    })";
```

You look at the Background Renderer implementation in the samples:
https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/blob/master/samples/hello_ar_c/app/src/main/cpp/background_renderer.cc